Pycharm reverts the selected keyboard layout
I start pycharm in my ubuntu 22.04 and try top change layout with meta+space (standard combination)
pycharm seems to revert it back immediately.
If i add alt+shift via tweaks - this combination works well.
No keymap with a 'space' button in the pycharm..
any ideas ?
I expecting meta+space will change the keyboard layout.
